# Count of specific value in column

Tags: r, survey

I have data from survey questionnaire like this:

```
    survey <- data.frame(
    ID = sample(1:10),
    Var1 = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    Var2=sample(c("DNK", "yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    Var3=sample(c("DNK", "PNA", "yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    Var4=sample(c("DNK", "PNA", "yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE)
   )
```

I want to know which variable has the most DNK and PNA responses.I think it would be a loop function but I can't seem to figure this out.
That is, I want an output with the count of PNA/DNK for each variable: 
e.g.)

```
Var3: DNK 4
Var3: DNK 3, PNA 1
Var4: DNK 1, PNA 3
```

Comment: `lapply(survey[, -1], table)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the replies. Using the responses provided, this is what I was looking for: 
`dnk=apply(subset[,1:dim(survey)[2]], 2, function(x) length(which(x=="DNK")))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
library(plyr)
apply(survey[,2:5],2,count)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use: `occurrences <- apply(survey, 2, table)`

This will return a list called `occurrences` where item *i* contains the number of occurrences of each element of column *i*.

Now it is only a matter of printing or storing the output (depending on what you want). You can print them by doing:

```
for (i in 1:length(occurrences)){
print(occurrences[i])
}
```